# What regex could match this pattern?

Tags: python, regex

The output I have is the following:

```
T 2020/03/05 16:06:41.565817 193.126.13.199:80 -> 10.8.0.4:55639 [AP] HTTP/1.1 200 OK..Date: Thu, 05 Mar 2020 16:06:41 GMT..Server: Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS)..Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT..Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, 
T 2020/03/05 16:06:46.727199 10.8.0.4:55642 -> 193.126.13.199:80 [AP] GET / HTTP/1.1..Host: www.radionova.fm..User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:72.0) Gecko/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8..Accept-Langu
T 2020/03/05 16:06:47.174078 193.126.13.199:80 -> 10.8.0.4:55642 [A] HTTP/1.1 200 OK..Date: Thu, 05 Mar 2020 16:06:46 GMT..Server: Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS)..Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT..Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache
```

How can I do a regex pattern to match only the [AP] rows?

Something like:

*T* **2020/03/05** **16:06:46.727199** **10.8.0.4:55642** *-> 193.126.13.199:80 [AP]* **GET / HTTP/1.1..Host: www.radionova.fm..User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:72.0)**

So.. the first group: 2020/03/05

Second group: 16:06:46.727199

Third group: 10.8.0.4:55642

Fourth group: GET / HTTP/1.1..Host: www.radionova.fm..User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:72.0)

I have the following python regex:

```
pattern = r'''T\s([^ ]+)\s([^ ]+)\s([^ ]+).*?[.]{2,}(.*?)[.]{2,}'''
```

Not working like I want..

Comment: Try `T\s([^ ]+)\s([^ ]+)\s([^ ]+)\s([^ ]+)\s([^ ]+)\s\[AP].*?\.{2}(.*?)\.{2}` https://regex101.com/r/7s5RQp/1

Comment: Not working like I want. Outputing the wrong information. Btw I tried this one *pattern = r'''T\s([^ ]+)\s([^ ]+)\s([^ ]+).*?[AP]{2,}(.*?)[.]{2,}'''* its working but missing information in the last parameter.. just showing half text I want the full line

Comment: I have updated it to match the whole line and the same groups https://regex101.com/r/k31jmR/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not the obvious `in` operator?

```
data = """
T 2020/03/05 16:06:41.565817 193.126.13.199:80 -> 10.8.0.4:55639 [AP] HTTP/1.1 200 OK..Date: Thu, 05 Mar 2020 16:06:41 GMT..Server: Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS)..Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT..Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, 
T 2020/03/05 16:06:46.727199 10.8.0.4:55642 -> 193.126.13.199:80 [AP] GET / HTTP/1.1..Host: www.radionova.fm..User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:72.0) Gecko/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8..Accept-Langu
T 2020/03/05 16:06:47.174078 193.126.13.199:80 -> 10.8.0.4:55642 [A] HTTP/1.1 200 OK..Date: Thu, 05 Mar 2020 16:06:46 GMT..Server: Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS)..Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT..Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache
"""

rows_ap = [(splitted[1], splitted[2], splitted[3], " ".join(splitted[7:]))
           for line in data.split("\n")
           if line and "[AP]" in line
           for splitted in [line.split(" ")]]

print(rows_ap)
```

Comment: That is not what I want. I want to separate all because I need each position, then i'll run a FOR to send it to database like results[x][0...4]. I really want to use regex

Answer (score 0):

You could add matching 2 extra parts matching a whitespace and non whitespace chars and match the `\[AP]` part

```
 T\s(\S+)\s(\S+)\s(\S+)\s\S+\s\S+\s\[AP].*?\.{2}(.*?)\.{2}.*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fxSLSk/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/oullyH)

```
import re

regex = r"T\s(\S+)\s(\S+)\s(\S+)\s\S+\s\S+\s\[AP].*?\.{2}(.*?)\.{2}.*"

test_str = ("T 2020/03/05 16:06:41.565817 193.126.13.199:80 -> 10.8.0.4:55639 [AP] HTTP/1.1 200 OK..Date: Thu, 05 Mar 2020 16:06:41 GMT..Server: Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS)..Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT..Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, \n"
    "T 2020/03/05 16:06:46.727199 10.8.0.4:55642 -> 193.126.13.199:80 [AP] GET / HTTP/1.1..Host: www.radionova.fm..User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:72.0) Gecko/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8..Accept-Langu\n"
    "T 2020/03/05 16:06:47.174078 193.126.13.199:80 -> 10.8.0.4:55642 [A] HTTP/1.1 200 OK..Date: Thu, 05 Mar 2020 16:06:46 GMT..Server: Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS)..Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT..Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache")

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):
    print (match.group())
```

Output

```
T 2020/03/05 16:06:41.565817 193.126.13.199:80 -> 10.8.0.4:55639 [AP] HTTP/1.1 200 OK..Date: Thu, 05 Mar 2020 16:06:41 GMT..Server: Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS)..Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT..Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, 
T 2020/03/05 16:06:46.727199 10.8.0.4:55642 -> 193.126.13.199:80 [AP] GET / HTTP/1.1..Host: www.radionova.fm..User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:72.0) Gecko/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8..Accept-Langu
```

Comment: @HenriqueMota Did you try it without the anchors `^` and `$` ? How are you using the pattern?

Comment: @Thefourthbird has helped me before.  Saw this thread and thought I'd take a stab at this.  May be interesting: https://regex101.com/r/LP9YdP/1